# Padding causes horizontal scroll - it increases the width

Tags: html, css, width, padding

Please look at this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
}

#header{
width:100%;
height:100px;
position:fixed;
display:inline-block;
background-color:red;
padding:0 10px 10px 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
         <div id="header-container">
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3hVvW/2/) .
The `header` must have 100% width and 10px padding from left,right and bottom. please look at this picture

[image]

this is the layout of `#header` by firebug. as you can see the right padding is not in the image because the 10px padding is added to the `#header` width (you can test it). how can I set 100% width for `#header` and 10px padding for left,right and bottom without increasing the width?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try this

```
 * , *:before, *:after{ 
     box-sizing:border-box; 
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
     -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
   }
```

or

```
 #header{
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 position:fixed;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:red;
 padding:0 10px 10px 10px;
 box-sizing:border-box;  /** add this **/
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
}
```

Comment: Just as a tip for those encountering this, it seems that at this point just about all browsers support the main box-sizing:border-box; version, so you likely don't need the -mox-, -webkit- and -ms- prefixes for most users. I suppose they're still helpful for maximizing compatibility, regardless.

Comment: Interestingly, i required the exact opposite. I just set this property to 'content-box' to allow my padding to trigger (vertical) overflow ! thx

Answer (score 6):

The CSS calc operator may prove helpful. With it, you can adjust the width that can be 'thrown off' when you specify left/right padding or left/right margin. Since you specified total left/right padding of 20px, then 20px would be what you need to subtract from the total with.

```
#header{
width: calc(100% - 20px);
height:100px;
position:fixed;
display:inline-block;
background-color:red;
padding:0 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `margin` .. or reduce your width with respect to your padding area.

```
#header{
    width:98%;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0 1% 10px 1%;
}
```

**Padding**

The padding clears an area around the content (inside the border) of an element. The padding is affected by the background color of the element.

**Margin**

The margin clears an area around an element (outside the border). The margin does not have a background color, and is completely transparent.

Comment: thanks for your reply, so how much must be the width of `header` and `header-container` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that you want want full width with padding. for this you can try this code:

```
#header{
width: initial;
height:100px;
position:fixed;
display:inline-block;
background-color:red;
padding:0 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

i just hope this will give desire output.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem `overflow-x: hidden;`