# How to remove unnecessary space using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple HTML webpage recently, and everything works perfectly, except for on the webpage you can scroll to the right and there's a strange space where there aren't any elements and that the background doesn't cover. I've gone over my code many times, but I just can't figure out what it is.

Screenshot of the problem:

[image: 1]

As for the code, here it is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Multiline to Singleline JS Converter">
        <meta name="author" content="Nomadical">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Multiline to Singleline,JS,Multiline to Singleline JS, Multiline to Singleline Converter, Nomadical" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon/ico" href="javascripticon.ico"/>
        <title>Multiline to Singleline JS</title>

    </head>
    <style>
        #header {
            background-color: white;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 95%;
            margin-top: 0px;
            top: 0;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
        }
        
        #headercontainer{
            padding-left: 5%;
        }

        #body {
            background-image: url(background.png);
            background-size: cover; 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: #464444;
        }

        #tablerow {
            width: 45%; 
        }
    </style>
    <body id="body">
        <div id="headercontainer">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                    Multiline to Singleline JS Converter
                </h1>
                <h4 style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                    The tool for converting all your complicated JS code into something that can be run in a browser bookmark
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 10%; width: 100%; position: relative;">
            <table style="width: 80%;"> <!-- Style for testing: border: 1px solid white; -->
                <tr>
                    <th id="tablerow">
                        <h1 style="color: white; width: 100%; text-align: center;"> <!-- Input In -->
                        Paste your singleline code here
                        </h1>
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;"></th>
                    <th id="tablerow">  <!-- Input Out -->
                        <h1 style="color: white; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                        Copy your singleline code from here
                        </h1>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th id="tablerow"> <!-- Input In -->
                        <textarea id="input" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></textarea>
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;"></th>
                    <th id="tablerow"> <!-- Input Out -->
                        <textarea id="output" readonly style="width: 100%; height: 500px; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></textarea>
                        <!--<input type="text" id="output2" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></textarea>-->
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 20px;"></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th id="tablerow">
                        <button type="button" id="submit" style="color: green; width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 25px;">Convert</button> 
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;"></th>
                    <th id="tablerow">
                        <button onclick="copy()" id="copy" type="button" style="color: green; width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 25px;">Copy Text</button> 
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            function copy() {
                const copy = document.getElementById("copy");
                copyText = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
                copy.innerText = "Copied!";
                setTimeout(() => {copy.innerText = "Copy Text";}, 2000);
            }
            
            document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "";
                output = "javascript: ";
                input = "";
                cache = "";
                comment = false;
                var textbox = document.getElementById("input").value;
                //var input = $('textbox').val().split('\n');
                //document.getElementById('output2').value= textbox;
                //var input = textbox.value.split("\n");
                for(var i = 0;i < textbox.length;i++){
                    line = textbox[i]
                    if (line == "/" && textbox[i + 1] == "/") {
                        comment = true;
                        i++
                    }
                    if (comment == false) {
                        if (line.indexOf('\n') > -1) {
                            if (line.indexOf(';') < 0 && cache != ";" && cache != "}" && cache != "{")
                            {
                            //if (textbox[i + 1] == "}") {
                            //    line = ""
                            //}
                                if (line == "\n" && textbox[i - 1] != "{" && textbox[i + 1] != "}") {
                                    line = "; "
                                }
                                else {
                                    line = ""
                                }
                            }
                            if (cache == ";") {
                                line = " "
                            }
                            if (cache == "{" || cache == "}") {
                                line = ""
                            }
                        }
                        if (line != " ") {
                        output += line
                        }
                        if (cache != " ")
                        {
                            if (line == " " && textbox[i - 1] != "\n") {
                                output += line
                            }
                        }
                        cache = line
                    }
                    if (comment == true) {
                        if (line != "\n") {
                            line = ""
                        }
                        else {
                            comment = false;
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code doesn't have the background image in it, so if you want to view that, you can download it here: [Click here](https://easyupload.io/oblsk6)

Comment: * {box-sizing: border-box;} - try add this to your css style

Comment: @digitalniweb That worked! Is there any way to mark a comment as the solution?

Comment: As far as I know there is not. I will make an answer, you can mark that one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Padding causes horizontal scroll - it increases the width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621584/padding-causes-horizontal-scroll-it-increases-the-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css style:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

For some reason this is not a default value. This will make all elements width calculated with padding included. Otherwise padding is added to width. Margin is still added on top of width. There is no solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#headercontainer{
  padding-left: 5%;
  width: 100%;
}
```