# Divs not responding

Tags: html, css

I have a container with two divs in it but for some reason their not centering themselves correctly, I am trying to make my website responsive currently. I would like the too html and css divs to stay in the center of the page no matter screen size. If you resize you'll see the divs move closer to the right and starts to hide itself.
Here's my code:

```css
.skills-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.skills-section .title p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(5, 1, 22);
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.leftside-rightside-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftside-rightside-wrapper .leftside {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.leftside .circle-profile-holder {
  min-width: 310px;
  height: 310px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #050416;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px 2px #efefef;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px;
}

.circle-profile-holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle-profile-holder .profile {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px 2px #efefef;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #050416;
}

.circle-profile-holder .profile .img {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #cecccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.circle-profile-holder .profile .img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle-profile-holder .profile .description {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px;
  grid-template-rows: 250px 250px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rightside .inform-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rightside .html-content {
  border: none;
  background: rgb(234, 234, 248);
  border-top-left-radius: 35%;
  border-top-right-radius: 67%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}

.rightside .css-content {
  background: rgb(226, 224, 224);
  border-top-left-radius: 32%;
  border-top-right-radius: 54%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 125px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
  border: none;
}

.rightside .js-content {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 203);
  border: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 48%;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 140%;
}

.rightside .php-content {
  border: none;
  background: rgb(255, 252, 252);
}

.rightside .inform-wrapper .top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.rightside .inform-wrapper .top p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar {
  width: 230px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar .pg-html {
  width: 90%;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar .pg-css {
  width: 84%;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar .pg-js {
  width: 15%;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar .pg-php {
  width: 35%;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.rightside .inform-wrapper .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
}

.inform-wrapper .bottom p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(2, 6, 19);
  padding: 15px;
}


/*Contact Section*/

.contact-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact-section .title-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 25px;
}

.contact-section .title-wrapper p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 12px;
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper input {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 32);
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(238, 53, 84);
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper form #textarea {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  margin-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
}

.form-wrapper form #textarea::placeholder {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.form-wrapper .information-submits {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-wrapper .information-submits p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 12);
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 650px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form-wrapper .information-submits .submit-btn {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(1, 1, 12);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-section .extra-information {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.contact-section .extra-information p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.contact-section .extra-information .links-to-social-medias a {
  margin: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
}


/*
Here's the responsive css which is supposed to place my styles into effect:
*/

@media screen and (max-width:1170px) {
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .html-content {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .css-content {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .php-content {
    display: none;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .js-content {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1022px) {
  .leftside .circle-profile-holder {
    display: none;
  }
  .leftside-rightside-wrapper .leftside {
    display: none;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside {
    width: 95%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .leftside-rightside-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    /* Stack elements vertically */
    align-items: center;
    /* Center items horizontally within the parent container */
  }
  .leftside,
  .rightside {
    width: 100%;
    /* Take full width on small screens */
    max-width: none;
    /* Reset max-width */
  }
  .rightside .inform-wrapper {
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* Adjust margin as needed */
  }
  /* Adjust font size and padding for smaller screens */
  .rightside .inform-wrapper .top p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .rightside .inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar {
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  .rightside .inform-wrapper .bottom p {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="skills-section">
  <div class="title">
    <p>My Skills</p>
  </div>
  <div class="leftside-rightside-wrapper">
    <div class="leftside">
      <div class="circle-profile-holder">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/08/27/00/08/cycling-8215968_640.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="profile">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/08/27/08/20/hiking-8216486_640.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="description">
            <p>Siure veritatis eius Nesciunt nobis repudiandae totam enim nulla. Jas stoa ti, I nea dwa fe.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <div class="html-content inform-wrapper">
        <div class="top">
          <p>HTML</p>
          <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="progress pg-html"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <p class="description">
            Architecto, adipisci perspiciatis quasi expedita dolorum, iste aperiam ipsa id impedit inventore doloremque quo quae eligendi, quia sapiente obcaecati doloribus deserunt quis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="css-content inform-wrapper">
        <div class="top">
          <p>CSS</p>
          <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="progress pg-css"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <p class="description">
            Architecto, adipisci perspiciatis quasi expedita dolorum, iste aperiam ipsa id impedit inventore doloremque quo quae eligendi, quia sapiente obcaecati doloribus deserunt quis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="js-content inform-wrapper">
        <div class="top">
          <p>JAVASCRIPT</p>
          <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="progress pg-js"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <p class="description">
            Architecto, adipisci perspiciatis quasi expedita dolorum, iste aperiam ipsa id impedit inventore doloremque quo quae eligendi, quia sapiente obcaecati doloribus deserunt quis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="php-content inform-wrapper">
        <div class="top">
          <p>PHP</p>
          <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="progress pg-php"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <p class="description">
            Architecto, adipisci perspiciatis quasi expedita dolorum, iste aperiam ipsa id impedit inventore doloremque quo quae eligendi, quia sapiente obcaecati doloribus deserunt quis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code that's causing my divs to not respond to different screen sizes?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about what isn't working the way you expect.  (I see the layout changing at several breakpoints, and it appears to be responding to the screen size pretty well, but if there's something specific that should be happening you need to tell us what it is.)

Comment: @Daniel Beck, as the screen gets smaller, the html and css div containers are not centering themselves.

Comment: Don't add comments, edit the question with specifics

Comment: There are dozens of divs in this.  Which ones aren't centered that should be?

Comment: @Daniel Beck the html and css divs.

Comment: Do you want to actually hide things or just pull them further down depending upon the screen size?

Comment: @Daniel Beck, I want them to be center on the page and I want their to be an equal amount of space on each side of the divs.

Comment: .....you mean the divs containing the headers "CSS" and "HTML".  Okay. That could have been expressed a lot more clearly.  I feel like I'm in a "who's on first" sketch here.

It's the padding on `.skills-section` bumping those to the right.

Comment: Please read the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621584/padding-causes-horizontal-scroll-it-increases-the-width

Comment: @Daniel Beck, can you answer it and show me the modified code? Because I removed it and it's not going into effect.

Comment: Please review [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem", meaning this specific problem, not every problem on every website :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to all CSS rules (for example using the "all" selector as seen below) to include the paddings in all `width` settings (if you don't, padding gets *added*   to whatever width, which can result in more than 100% of the screen width and similar):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.skills-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.skills-section .title p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(5, 1, 22);
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.leftside-rightside-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftside-rightside-wrapper .leftside {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.leftside .circle-profile-holder {
  min-width: 310px;
  height: 310px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #050416;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px 2px #efefef;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px;
}

.circle-profile-holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle-profile-holder .profile {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px 2px #efefef;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #050416;
}

.circle-profile-holder .profile .img {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #cecccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.circle-profile-holder .profile .img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle-profile-holder .profile .description {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px;
  grid-template-rows: 250px 250px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rightside .inform-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rightside .html-content {
  border: none;
  background: rgb(234, 234, 248);
  border-top-left-radius: 35%;
  border-top-right-radius: 67%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}

.rightside .css-content {
  background: rgb(226, 224, 224);
  border-top-left-radius: 32%;
  border-top-right-radius: 54%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 125px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
  border: none;
}

.rightside .js-content {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 203);
  border: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 48%;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 140%;
}

.rightside .php-content {
  border: none;
  background: rgb(255, 252, 252);
}

.rightside .inform-wrapper .top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.rightside .inform-wrapper .top p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar {
  width: 230px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar .pg-html {
  width: 90%;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar .pg-css {
  width: 84%;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar .pg-js {
  width: 15%;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar .pg-php {
  width: 35%;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.rightside .inform-wrapper .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
}

.inform-wrapper .bottom p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(2, 6, 19);
  padding: 15px;
}


/*Contact Section*/

.contact-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact-section .title-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 25px;
}

.contact-section .title-wrapper p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 12px;
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper input {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 32);
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(238, 53, 84);
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
}

.contact-section .form-wrapper form #textarea {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  margin-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
}

.form-wrapper form #textarea::placeholder {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.form-wrapper .information-submits {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-wrapper .information-submits p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 12);
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 650px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form-wrapper .information-submits .submit-btn {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(1, 1, 12);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-section .extra-information {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.contact-section .extra-information p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.contact-section .extra-information .links-to-social-medias a {
  margin: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
}


/*
Here's the responsive css which is supposed to place my styles into effect:
*/

@media screen and (max-width:1170px) {
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .html-content {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .css-content {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .php-content {
    display: none;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .js-content {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1022px) {
  .leftside .circle-profile-holder {
    display: none;
  }
  .leftside-rightside-wrapper .leftside {
    display: none;
  }
  .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside {
    width: 95%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .leftside-rightside-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    /* Stack elements vertically */
    align-items: center;
    /* Center items horizontally within the parent container */
  }
  .leftside,
  .rightside {
    width: 100%;
    /* Take full width on small screens */
    max-width: none;
    /* Reset max-width */
  }
  .rightside .inform-wrapper {
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* Adjust margin as needed */
  }
  /* Adjust font size and padding for smaller screens */
  .rightside .inform-wrapper .top p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .rightside .inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar {
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  .rightside .inform-wrapper .bottom p {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="skills-section">
  <div class="title">
    <p>My Skills</p>
  </div>
  <div class="leftside-rightside-wrapper">
    <div class="leftside">
      <div class="circle-profile-holder">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/08/27/00/08/cycling-8215968_640.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="profile">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/08/27/08/20/hiking-8216486_640.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="description">
            <p>Siure veritatis eius Nesciunt nobis repudiandae totam enim nulla. Jas stoa ti, I nea dwa fe.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <div class="html-content inform-wrapper">
        <div class="top">
          <p>HTML</p>
          <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="progress pg-html"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <p class="description">
            Architecto, adipisci perspiciatis quasi expedita dolorum, iste aperiam ipsa id impedit inventore doloremque quo quae eligendi, quia sapiente obcaecati doloribus deserunt quis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="css-content inform-wrapper">
        <div class="top">
          <p>CSS</p>
          <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="progress pg-css"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <p class="description">
            Architecto, adipisci perspiciatis quasi expedita dolorum, iste aperiam ipsa id impedit inventore doloremque quo quae eligendi, quia sapiente obcaecati doloribus deserunt quis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="js-content inform-wrapper">
        <div class="top">
          <p>JAVASCRIPT</p>
          <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="progress pg-js"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <p class="description">
            Architecto, adipisci perspiciatis quasi expedita dolorum, iste aperiam ipsa id impedit inventore doloremque quo quae eligendi, quia sapiente obcaecati doloribus deserunt quis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="php-content inform-wrapper">
        <div class="top">
          <p>PHP</p>
          <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="progress pg-php"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <p class="description">
            Architecto, adipisci perspiciatis quasi expedita dolorum, iste aperiam ipsa id impedit inventore doloremque quo quae eligendi, quia sapiente obcaecati doloribus deserunt quis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the skills-section container itself needed flexbox, I removed all padding and margins and updated the padding and margins for the child containers. Here's the result:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1170px) {
    .skills-section {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding:0;
    }

    .skills-section .title p {
        display:none;
    }

.skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding:0;
}

.skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .html-content {
    border-radius:0;
    margin:0;
}

.skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .css-content {
    border-radius:0;
    margin-top:12px;
}

.skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .php-content {
    display:none;
}

.skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside .js-content {
    display:none;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:1022px) {
    .leftside .circle-profile-holder {
        display:none;
    }

    .leftside-rightside-wrapper .leftside {
        display:none;
    }

    .skills-section .leftside-rightside-wrapper .rightside {
        width: 95%;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding:10px;
        justify-content:flex-start;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.skills-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.skills-section .title p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(5, 1, 22);
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.leftside-rightside-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow for wrapping on smaller screens */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.leftside {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 300px; /* Limit the width for responsiveness */
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px; /* Add margin for spacing between elements */
}

.leftside .circle-profile-holder {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 310px; /* Limit the width for responsiveness */
  height: 310px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #050416;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px 2px #efefef;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px;
}

.circle-profile-holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle-profile-holder .profile {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px 2px #efefef;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #050416;
}

/* Add your .profile styles here as before */

.rightside {
  width: 70%; /* Adjust width for responsiveness */
  max-width: 800px; /* Limit the width for responsiveness */
  margin: 10px; /* Add margin for spacing between elements */
}

.rightside .inform-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Add your .html-content, .css-content, .js-content, .php-content styles here as before */

.rightside .inform-wrapper .top p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar {
  width: 230px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(82, 82, 245, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px auto; /* Center the progress bar */
}

/* Add your .pg-html, .pg-css, .pg-js, .pg-php styles here as before */

.inform-wrapper .top .progress-bar .pg-php {
  width: 35%; /* Adjust the progress bar width as needed */
}
```

Comment: With these CSS modifications, your divs should remain centered and responsive as the screen size changes.